# Jquery add class to input checkbox field

Tags: jquery

I would like to make add / remove a class to a div that holds a checkbox.

I am 80% there, though am not sure on the right syntax to look at whether the input item is checked or unchecked. So I can add or remove the class appropriate.

Essentially I know it needs to look like:

```
if("$thechecks #item-" + req).attr('checked') { 
   $("#item-" + req).addClass("item-select");
} else {
   $("#item-" + req).removeClass("item-select");
}
```

Any help / thoughts would be really appreciated.

---

I made a small fiddle of my code to-date.

http://jsfiddle.net/brandrally/vc5wgpk2/

**// Javascript //**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#thechecks input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
            var req = $(this).val();
            $("#item-" + req).addClass("item-select");
        });
    });
```

**// HTML //**

```
<div id="thechecks">

<div id="item-1">
<label><input name="element[]" type="checkbox" value="1" > One</label>
</div>

<div id="item-2">
<label><input name="element[]" type="checkbox" value="2" > Two </label>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you could use `toggleClass()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#thechecks input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
        var req = $(this).val();
        $("#item-" + req).toggleClass("item-select");
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vc5wgpk2/1/)

Comment: I cannot accept it (as I need to wait 10 minutes), though thank you. The toggle class was all i needed!

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc5wgpk2/2/)

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#thechecks input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
        var req = $(this).val();
        if($("#item-"+req).hasClass("item-select"))
        {
            $("#item-" + req).removeClass("item-select");
        } else {
            $("#item-" + req).addClass("item-select");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/brandrally/vc5wgpk2/)

**Try this**

Use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`

```
//  $("#item-" + req).addClass("item-select");
 $("#item-" + req).toggleClass("item-select");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery `closest` and `toggleClass`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name^=element]').on('change', function(e) {//input name starting with `element`
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('div[id^=item]').toggleClass('check', this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');//fire on page load
});
```

```css
.check {
  background: skyblue;
}

div[id^=item] {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thechecks">

  <div id="item-1">
    <label>
      <input name="element[]" type="checkbox" value="1">One</label>
  </div>

  <div id="item-2">
    <label>
      <input name="element[]" type="checkbox" value="2" checked='checked'>Two</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui>
<li><label><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />Apple</label></li>
</ui>

//code before
<div id="wr" class="wrapper">
//code after
```

> Add/remove class to the `<div id="wr" class="wrapper"> by checkbox`
>   click:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox2').click(function () {
       $('#wr').toggleClass('on');
    });
});
</script>
```